# Declarations at the GHCi prompt

Tags: haskell, syntax, declaration, ghci

I have just installed Haskell Platform for Windows (version 2011.2.0.1), and started to work through the HaskellQuestions.pdf

The second question requires "x = 3" as the answer. But when I enter this into GHCi I get

```
GHCi, version 7.0.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package ffi-1.0 ... linking ... done.
Prelude> x = 3

<interactive>:1:3: parse error on input `='
Prelude>
```

Why? I checked the answer, and I am right. Whats the matter with the equals sign?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In GHCi, to assign a value, you have to go

```
let x = 3
```

In regular Haskell code, `x = 3` would be valid (see NB below).

[Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/)'s [Getting Started](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/getting-started.html) page has lots of useful info about using GHCI.

You can also look at the [documentation for GHCi](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/ghci.html) (but personally, I find Real World Haskell a little more digestable).

N.B. As [EdvardM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289420/edvardm) notes in the comments, the syntax for using `let` in this context is from [Haskell's do notation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#ghci-stmts) (if you're just beginning, don't stress yourself out if you're a little lost. Take your time, have fun, and it ought to make sense in no time).

Comment: Thanks. Did I miss some documentation?

Comment: No. I had the same exact issue when I started too :-). Haskell's documentation for GHCi does note using let, but it's very easy to miss

Comment: Yes. Once you understand how Haskell works, and in order to be able to change the x (you may want to say that x is something different later on), you need to use let syntax. With interactive tool, you're experimenting stuff and changing code all the time, and you'd be bitten hard if you couldn't rebind symbols.